# htaccess rewrite condition a folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect demo.mydomain.net/p/ to mydomain.net/.

I saved the .htaccess on my demo.mydomain.net/p/ folder but it gives me the 500 Internal Server Error.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.mydomain\.net\p$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.demo\.mydomain\.net\p$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.net" [R=301,L]
```

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you test your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} demo\.mydomain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mydomain.net/ [R=301,L]
```